# stanford core nlp: sentiment tree and pos tags

Tags: stanford-nlp

The sentiment annotation provides with an annotated tree with attached annotations on its nodes, used for predicting sentiment.
This tree is different from the parse tree, provided by the parse annotation.
For example, for this sentence:

```
I don't know half of you half as well as I should like; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.
```

This is the parse tree:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP (PRP I))
      (VP (VBP do) (RB n't)
        (VP (VB know)
          (NP
            (NP (NN half))
            (PP (IN of)
              (NP (PRP you))
              (ADVP (DT half) (RB as) (RB well))))
          (SBAR (IN as)
            (S
              (NP (PRP I))
              (VP (MD should)
                (VP (VB like))))))))
    (: ;)
    (CC and)
    (S
      (NP (PRP I))
      (VP (VBP like)
        (NP
          (NP
            (QP (JJR less) (IN than) (NN half)))
          (PP (IN of)
            (NP (PRP you) (DT half))))
        (ADVP
          (ADVP (RB as) (RB well))
          (SBAR (IN as)
            (S
              (NP (PRP you))
              (VP (VBP deserve)))))))
    (. .)))
```

This is the sentiment annotated tree:

```
(ROOT
  (@S
    (@S
      (@S
        (S (NP I)
          (VP
            (@VP (VBP do) (RB n't))
            (VP
              (@VP (VB know)
                (NP (NP half)
                  (PP
                    (@PP (IN of) (NP you))
                    (ADVP (DT half)
                      (@ADVP (RB as) (RB well))))))
              (SBAR (IN as)
                (S (NP I)
                  (VP (MD should) (VP like)))))))
        (: ;))
      (CC and))
    (S (NP I)
      (VP
        (@VP (VBP like)
          (NP
            (NP (JJR less)
              (@QP (IN than) (NN half)))
            (PP (IN of)
              (NP (PRP you) (DT half)))))
        (ADVP
          (ADVP (RB as) (RB well))
          (SBAR (IN as)
            (S (NP you) (VP deserve)))))))
  (. .))
```

Why are the trees slightly different? I think that verbs are verb phrases in the sentiment tree, nouns noun phrases etc.

What do these "@" mean?

How can I access the pos tags of the nodes, while iterating through the sentiment tree? Is it the value of the node?

If I want to get the pos tag of sentiment tree nodes from the parse tree, is searching for the parse tree node with the same yield(leaves) the only way? If the trees were the same, I could iterate through both of them for example.

What is the suggested way to get the pos tag of sentiment nodes?